# Why $scope is not defined here in the following code

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working with Angular 1.x and here is the code which was giving errors:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular JS Controllers</title>
  </head>   
  <body>
    <div ng-app="app">
      <h1>Controllers</h1>
       <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
         <p>{{message}}</p>
       </div> 
     </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      angular.module('app', [])
         .controller('MainCtrl', [$scope, function($scope){
           $scope.message = "Hello";
         }]);
    </script>
   </body>
  </html>
```

It was giving error *ReferenceError: $scope is not defined*

I thought may be $scope is not getting injected then I addded a dependency of $scope in the array to the 'app' module like this :-

```
angular.module('app', [$scope])
```

but to no avail. But what worked was the following code:-

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular JS Controllers</title>
  </head>   
  <body>
    <div ng-app="app">
      <h1>Controllers</h1>
       <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
         <p>{{ctrl.message}}</p>
       </div> 
     </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      angular.module('app', [])
         .controller('MainCtrl', [function(){
           this.message = "Hello";
         }]);
    </script>
   </body>
  </html>
```

I am referring the message model in HTML using ctrl.messaage, only then its appearing not otherwise.But why!!

Why can't I use $scope here, if I can how!!
/
Basically what is the difference between this and the earlier code?

Comment: just put $scope as `'$scope'` when calling the array. Like `.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){`

Comment: Should be `...['$scope', function($scope)...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it shoulde be like this.

```
angular.module('app', [])
     .controller('MainCtrl', ["$scope", function($scope){
       $scope.message = "Hello";
     }]);
```

and it's better use `controllerAs` syntax

```
angular.module('app', [])
     .controller('MainCtrl', ["$scope", function($scope){
      var vm = this;
       vm.message = "Hello";
     }]);
```

and in view use

```
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
```

Comment: Why it's better to use controllerAs syntax.

Comment: please see this https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this

```
angular.module('app', [])
     .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
       $scope.message = "Hello";
     }]);
```

Answer (score 2):

When using an array as the second argument of the controller-method you have to use strings as values. This allows you to rename dependency modules.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      angular.module('app', [])
         .controller('MainCtrl', ["$scope", function($scope){
           $scope.message = "Hello";
         }]);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add quotes around `$scope` when you're injecting it into your controller. AngularJS will look at these string variables to determine what it needs to safely inject into your application.

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.message = "Hello";
}]);
```